# How to create XSD schema from XML with this kind of structure (in .net)?

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, dataset, orm

Here's the problem: my input is XML file that looks something like:

```
<BaseEntityClassInfo>
<item>
  <key>BaseEntityClassInfo.SomeField</key>
  <value>valueData1</value>
</item>
<item>
  <key>BaseEntityClassInfo.AdditionalDataClass.SomeOtherField</key>
  <value>valueData2</value>
</item>
<item>
  <key>BaseEntityClassInfo.AdditionalDataClass.AnotherClassInfo.DisplayedText</key>
  <value>valueData3</value>
</item>
...
...
</BaseEntityClassInfo>
```

The `<key>` element somehow describes entity classes fields and relationships (used in some other app that I don't have access to) and the `<value>` stores the actual data that I need.

My goal is to programatically generate a typed Dataset from this XML that could then be used for creating reports. I thought of building some XSD schema from input XML file first and then use this schema to generate Dataset but I'm not sure how to do that. The problem is that I don't want all data in one table, I need several tables with relationships based on the `<key>` value so I guess I need to infer relational structure from XML `<key>` data in some way. Are there other ways? Should I be using XSLT, Linq2XML, something else?

So what do you think? How could this be done and what would be the best approach?
Any advice, ideas, suggestions would be *really* appreciated!
Anyone? There's some additional info in comments bellow...

Comment: Which version of .NET are you working with?

Comment: Ugh. Why in the world did the author of this decide to implement Entity-Attribute-Value **in XML**?  XML was largely designed to *eliminate* this kind of mess.

Comment: @Aaronaught I agree, it's ugly and makes no sense but that's what I got unfortunately...

Comment: Is there any other information, like column types?  Or are they all just strings?

Comment: @Aaronaught there's only strings as far as I know

Comment: One more question: Do you really, really need a *typed* dataset, or would it be sufficient just to populate a generic `DataSet` with the correct tables and relationships?  I'm just wondering what you would even *do* with a typed dataset that is effectively a one-off - unless the "keys" in the source XML are always exactly the same.

Comment: The more I look at this problem, the more it seems like a total dead-end.  How do you determine which relationships are one-to-one and which ones are one-to-many?  Or are they all one-to-one (in which case, what good does it do to generate a `DataSet`)?  Let's say you have two keys called `BaseEntityClassInfo.AdditionalDataClass.AnotherClassInfo.DisplayedText` - does that mean that the `BaseEntityClassInfo` has two `AdditionalDataClass` relations, or just one `AdditionalDataClass` with two `AnotherClassInfo` relations?

Comment: @Aaronaught Yes I need to construct typed Dataset somehow. This Dataset would be then used for creating reports with Crystal reports, and yes the "keys" should be always the same only "values" (the actual data) would be different.

Comment: @Aaronaught there should be no duplicate "key" entries, but there are one-to-many relationships

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't really be able to use any XML tools to build your Dataset because the data you need isn't stored in XML format: it's stored in the format that "some other app" is using. If it looked like:

```
<BaseEntityClassInfo SomeField="valueData1">
  <AdditionalDataClass SomeOtherField="valueData2">
    <AnotherClassInfo DisplayedText="valueData3">
  </AdditionalDataClass>
</BaseEntityClassInfo>
```

Then you could use the standard XML handlers in .Net, but since it's not, the best you can do is pull the key and value out as pairs of strings and then write your own code to parse the key into the data entities you need (for example, split the key on periods, then recursively match or create data structures).

Comment: There's a considerable gap between "doesn't match the default XML generated by DataSet" and "isn't data in XML format".

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your data I'll have to guess, but it looks like the xml could be based on a class structure like:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class BaseEntityClassInfo
{
  public string SomeField {get; set;}
  public AdditionalDataClass _AdditionalDataClass {get; set;}

  public class AdditionalDataClass
  {
    public string SomeOtherField {get; set;}
    public AnotherClassInfo _AnotherClassInfo {get; set;}    
  }

  public class AnotherClassInfo
  {
    public string DisplayedText {get; set;}
  }

  public BaseEntityClassInfo BaseEntityClassInfoCreate()
  {
      BaseEntityClassInfo instance =
          new AdditionalDataClass
            {
                SomeField = "valueData1",
                _AdditionalDataClass =
                  new AdditionalDataClass
                      {
                          SomeOtherField = "ValueData2",
                          _AnotherClassInfo =
                              new AnotherClassInfo { DisplayedText = "valueData3" }
                      }
            };
      return instance;
  }

}
```

... and that the class structure is then serialized into XML.

This structure can be extended with your real data and if you end up with say

```
List<BaseEntityClassInfo>
```

this could be the DataSource of your DataSet.

Comment: you're right about class structure but what I need is to somehow construct xsd schema from this mess not just fill dataset with the data....